# Only the index in www points to different page

Tags: html, apache, no-www

I have the following issue:

When I tried to reach www.example.com/index.html I got a different page than the page example.com/index.html

That problem is only on the main index file. Everything else is ok.

e.g. www.example.com/folder/  is the same as example.com/folder/

I have double check the dns/binding setting.

www is an alias to example.com

Also, I open the source code from index.html in folder ../www/example.com/index.html  The code is the same as the code in the /public_html/example.com/index.html

How can be fixed?

Comment: What is the actual site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-install the WP and check again